# Deleted answer visible

Tags: discussion

I'm used to be able to see my own deleted answers, and it makes sense: this way I can undelete them if I want. But I also can see others' deleted answers. Is this on purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct; the ability to view (and act on) deleted questions and answers is a privilege earned at 10k reputation:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: Thanks. Does this also mean I should be able to undelete them? I don't see any link for this.

Comment: @Stevenvh, this means you are part of a group that can vote to delete and undelete. In general if you are not sure why it was deleted and it was moderator action, please just ask us in chat. We would love to help you learn the ropes of being a user past 10k rep as we only have 3.

Comment: @Kortuk - Don't worry, number 4 is on his way: Thomas O. And the way he's going Olin Lathrop may be next :-)

Comment: @stevenvh, I am just saying, chat is a great place to discuss and learn and you can just flag me there with an @kortuk and I can respond later back. We will have you at expert level in no time flat.